# On the fourth power $2^4 + 15045^4 + 26870^4 + 34090^4 = 37239^4$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

The Diophantine equation,

$$x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4+x_4^4 = z^4\tag1$$

can be solved with $x_1 = 0$ (Elkies), or as the title shows, with $x_1 = 2$ (Wroblewski). See link [here](http://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/%7Ejwr/eslp/414.txt).

**Q:** Can $(1)$ be solved in the ***integers*** with $x_1 = 1$,

$$1+x_2^4+x_3^4+x_4^4 = z^4\tag2$$

or is there a congruential constraint that prevents this?

**P.S.** Anyone has the computing power to extend Wroblewski's table? He created that back in 2009 (with slower computers). One helpful fact is that all *primitive* solutions have the form,

$$x_0^4+5^4(x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4) = y_1^4$$

or three terms are always multiples of $5$.

Comment: Even if no congruential constraint prevents the equation, there might still be no solution.

Comment: Is there any explanation on how Wrobleski created his list?

Comment: Well, $1 + 0^4 + 0^4 + 0^4 = 1^4$ (in particular, there is no congruential constraint). Are you looking for solutions without zeros?

Comment: @JesperPetersen: He may have used modified tree algorithms, etc, which should facilitate computation. Also, if you look at the list, he groups together the three terms that are multiples of 5, so at the very least he used that basic congruential constraint.

Comment: Is there a proof somewhere of the primitive form (_i.e.,_ that $5$ divides three of the terms)?

Comment: @KierenMacMillan: This nice property relies on the fact that $k+1$ is ***prime*** for power $k=4$. There is a more general statement. **Theorem:** For $k$ $k$th powers and co-prime terms,
$$x_1^k+x_2^k+x_3^k+\dots+x_k^k = z^k$$
***if $k+1$ is prime***, then there is one $x_i$ such that  $z^k-x_i^k$ is divisible by $(k+1)^k$. This is based on _Fermat's Little Theorem_. Kindly see this [MO post](http://mathoverflow.net/q/206755/12905).

Comment: If $gcd(x_0,10) = 1$ then the equation can be simplified to $x_0^4+10^4\left(x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4\right)=y_1^4$. I have searched for $x_0 \in \{1,3,7,9\}$ with the limit $y_1 \leq 4 \times 10^7$. No solutions.

Comment: @klajok: Thanks, klajok.